# primefaces and inputtextarea no copy possible

Tags: jsf, select, primefaces, copy

Hallo I am using Primefaces 6.2 on JBoss EAP 7

I have a simple dialog which contains a textarea

```
<p:dialog id="messageDialog" widgetVar="messageDialog" styleClass="messageDialog">
<h3>Message</h3>
<h:inputTextarea value="#{detailController.messageContent}" readonly="false" cols="60" rows="25"/>
</p:dialog>
```

My problem is that the display text cannot be selected and copied.
I have searched and found solutions to disable editing in textareas. 
What is my mistake here?

Comment: Please test what happens if you don't use a `p:dialog` it works? or if you use an `p:inputTextArea` it works too?

Comment: p:inputTextArea does not work either. I need the p:dialog because this code is meant to display additional information for a datatable enty.

Comment: **TEST** without a `p:dialog` to see if it plays a role. A plain div (with `jsf:id="..."`) could replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have sovled it.
Using an overlayPanel instead of dialog makes the textarea selectable.

```
<p:commandLink value="Anzeigen" id="nachrichtAnzeigen"></p:commandLink>


<p:overlayPanel id="messageDialog" for="nachrichtAnzeigen" modal="true">
<h3>Message</h3>
<p:inputTextarea value="#{detailController.messageContent}" readonly="false" cols="60" rows="25"/>
</p:overlayPanel>
```